# Unable to change root password under single user mode

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, password-recovery

I'm using redhat el 5.4. I was trying to change the root password under single user mode. I got no error when I ran passwd.

However, when I boot from normal mode, my new password is still not accepted.

Appreciate your help

Comment: Is there any chance you are mounting a new /etc on a different partition once booted?

Comment: It finally worked after several tries. I don't know what happened though. Thanks for looking into it anyway

Comment: No problem, please add and accept your comment as an answer so the question is removed from unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked after several tries. I don't know what happened though. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Often the reason you can't change the password is because the boot volume is mounted as read-only. Try mounting your root filesystem with `mount -w` before trying to change the password.